# jQuery simle drop down menu . it doesnt work properly

Tags: drop-down-menu, slidetoggle

Here is my code. The class of `.dropdown-menu` is menu botton (where release the code when you hover over it) and class `.dropdown-menu` is its `li` child
thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.dropdown-toggle').hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).children('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: please post the full HTML